# how to rename a two-word(for example; 'manager id') column name in MySQL

Tags: mysql

i tried using this code below
ALTER TABLE table_name change "MANAGER ID" TO manager_id;

error message received:
1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '"MANAGER ID" TO manager_id' at line 1 0.000 sec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct syntax is:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name RENAME COLUMN `MANAGER ID` TO manager_id;
```

Comment: thank you zakaria

Answer (score 0):

According to [this question and answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/124083/mysql-how-to-quote-or-escape-field-names) your are using the wrong quotes. It should be

```
`MANAGER ID`
```

[See also the reference documentation.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifiers.html)